# Electron/Netralinojs source source code "protection"

Tags: javascript, electron, node-webkit, asar, neutralinojs

I am evaluating which framework to create a desktop app. A requirement I have is that the source code "protection" (no one should see the original source code).

For Neautrlinojs I have found this:
https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/issues/153#issuecomment-817842757
*Now we are using the .asar format (But it is .neu in our scenario). Therefore, I will close this issue. Thanks for reporting the issue/idea.*

But, as I know, the sourcecode (js) of an asar file che be obtained.
Is there a way to make impossible to get the "original" code from the build of Neautrlinojs or Electron?

I know that in a build made with [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/),  source code is very difficult to be obtained

For this kind of requirement, which framework is the most suitable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you need source code protection you need to use a tool that builds your source code to a native binary. NW.js allows for this by capturing your JS code running in memory in the V8 engine (a "V8 Snapshot"). Which means you need to run it's `nwjc` tool on each platform to capture it running in memory.

Other tools exist for creating Cross-Platform Desktop Apps (XPDAs):

- https://xpda.net

However if you want to use JavaScript as your source code, your only real option is NW.js, or to store it on a remote server and access it via the internet.

- https://nwjs.io - Official website
- https://nwutils.io - Community website